# formatte spring batch output object using spring API annotations formatters not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-annotations

Trying to format an object before writing the result to a text file using spring batch but I don't get the expected result.
I want to use the spring API annotation format, `@NumberFormat` for numbers and `@DateTimeFormat` for date because I have several objects to format and I do not want to waste time creating formatting services

The model:

```
public class Type_0 {

@NumberFormat(pattern="###,###.###")
private BigDecimal typeEnregistrement= BigDecimal.valueOf(123456789.123);

@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy")
private Date dateCreationFichier;

@NumberFormat(pattern="###,###.###")
public BigDecimal  getTypeEnregistrement() {
    return typeEnregistrement;
}
@NumberFormat(pattern="###,###.###")
public void setTypeEnregistrement(BigDecimal  typeEnregistrement) {
    this.typeEnregistrement = typeEnregistrement;
}

@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy")
public Date getDateCreationFichier() {
    return dateCreationFichier;
}
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy")
public void setDateCreationFichier(Date dateCreationFichier) {
    this.dateCreationFichier = dateCreationFichier;
}

@Override
 public String toString() {

return typeEnregistrement+""+typeEmetteur+numEmetteur+"      
"+TypeDest+numDest+dateCreationFichier;    }
}
```

The writer:

```
@Bean
public FlatFileItemWriter<Type_0> writer() {

    FlatFileItemWriter<Type_0> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<Type_0>();
    writer.setResource(new FileSystemResource("c:/upload/b2.txt"));
    DelimitedLineAggregator<Type_0> delLineAgg = new DelimitedLineAggregator<>();
    delLineAgg.setDelimiter(";");
    writer.setLineAggregator(delLineAgg);
    return writer;
}
```

The processor:

```
@Override
public Type_0 process(final Type_0 item) throws Exception {


    DefaultFormattingConversionService conversionService =
            new DefaultFormattingConversionService(false);
    conversionService.addFormatterForFieldAnnotation(
            new NumberFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory());
    Type_0 t0=new Type_0();
    t0=item;
    DataBinder dataBinder = new DataBinder(t0);
    dataBinder.setConversionService(conversionService);

    return t0;
}
```

Expected result is: 123.456.789,123 0000125      04.24.2007

but I have in the output file: 123456789.123 0000125      2007-04-24

Comment: can someone help me please

Comment: Is the writer code provided correct? can you provide more detail code for writer.

Comment: SushilBehera yes the code provided is correct, we just instanciate a flatFileItemWriter with Type_0, the object Type_0 is setted on the reader with dataBaseResult and returned by the processor

Comment: I can't see from what you shared how you could get the current incorrect result (`123456789.123 0000125 2007-04-24`). Where is the formatting happening? Please share [a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to reproduce the case to be able to help you.

Comment: Formatting data is happening on Type_0 Object with annotations NumberFormat and DateTimeFormat.        what if i want to print my data into a file using a special format or pattern, should i use springFreamwork's formatter or defin mine using a new annotation or java's formatter. so i guess that the spring's formatter format data only to output when printing data without changing the actual value? while the core java formatter change the actual value ?